# Preg match patterns for PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

could you help me with preg_match patterns for php and js, I want users to be abel to enter only number `

`from 0.5 то 8.`

The step between number is 0.5 i.e.

```
 0.5 , 1 , 1.5 , 2, 2.5 and so one up to 8
```

so users can't input numbers like:

```
2.3 2.7  and so on
```

Comment: Have you even tried to make one on your own ? Please try making one, and if you get problems, then ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript

```
var string = '7.5';
var pattern = new RegExp('^([1-8]|([0-7]\.5))$');

pattern.test(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Php:

```
<?php
$string = '7.5';
var_dump(preg_match('~^([1-8]|([0-7]\.5))$~', $string));
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/W2i2H)